# spaCy Pattern Matching - OR statements

Tags: python, spacy

is there a way to use or apply "OR" logic to pattern matcher? Something like can be done with regex? I don't want to have to create individual parsers for each occurrence, if possible (car, boat, bus, for example). I am also thinking that if I can do that, I can use a script to generate my rules. Any help would be appreciated.

Can I do something like the below, but without regex? Obviously, bus in this case might pick up other things.

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

matcher.add("VEHICLE", None,
            [{"LOWER":{"REGEX":"car|boat|bus"}}]
           )

text = "I saw a car pulling a boat today, which was really funny. I also saw a bus pulling a boat."

doc = nlp(text)
matches = matcher(doc)
```

Comment: Can you add an exhaustive list of positive and negative examples?

Comment: Do you mean `matcher.add("VEHICLE", None, [{"LOWER":"car"}, {"LOWER": "boat"}, {"LOWER": "bus"}])`?

Comment: Thanks all. That confirms what I had assumed. I thought I might be able to shortcut the list in some way. Appreciate the input.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov what does a negative example look like? I might have overlooked that in the docs.

Comment: What you don't like to be picked up

Comment: What do you mean by "shortcut the list"? Build the `patterns` dynamically from a list?

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov what is an example of a negative list? I get that it is things you don't want picked up. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: You want to find "boat" but you don't want your algo to find "boatless". "boatless" is negative example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a list of items you want to use as patterns, create a list of dictionaries from it and pass as the third argument to `matcher.add()`:

```py
l = ['car', 'boat', 'bus']
patterns = [{"LOWER":x} for x in l]
matcher.add("VEHICLE", None, patterns)
>>> for _, start, end in matcher(doc):
    print(doc[start:end].text)
car
boat
bus
boat
```

The `patterns` will look like `[{'LOWER': 'car'}, {'LOWER': 'boat'}, {'LOWER': 'bus'}]`.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor! Greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @aab's answer is better.
this will match the phrase "car boat bus"

Answer (score 1):

The `Matcher` supports `IN` and `NOT_IN` operators that match values in lists:

```py
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.blank("en")
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
l = ['car', 'boat', 'bus']
matcher.add("VEHICLE", [[{"LOWER": {"IN": l}}]])
doc = nlp("This is a car.")
matches = matcher(doc)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    print(nlp.vocab.strings[match_id], doc[start:end])
```

Output:

```
VEHICLE car
```

See: https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#adding-patterns-attributes-extended